# How does SQLyog communicate with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and the MySQL.Net connector. I have a query that on VS takes about 20 seconds to complete. On SQLyog, the exact same query takes less than a second.  I did a Wireshark trace of the two queries.  The VS query uses plain text to and from the server.  SQLyog uses some strange format and is unreadable. Whats more, the SQLyog query does it all in 3 packets: a request, response and final ACK.  The VS does it in 10 packets: request, two responses, ACK, two more responses, ACK, two more responses and final ACK. And the result is that two rows are returned in both cases. Does anyone know why SQLyog is so much faster and what interface they use?

Terry

Comment: See if you can disable compression on the SQLyog connection.  There are many connectors but fundamentally only one wire protocol, though it does support optional compression and TLS.  Compression seems like a likely candidate for the difference on the wire, but 20 seconds is far more difficult to explain and is probably not related to what's happening on the wire.

Answer (score 2):

SQLyog uses [mysql's c api](http://sqlyogkb.webyog.com/article/166-what-is-sqlyog):

> Written entirely in C/C++/Win32 APIs using native MySQL C APIs. No wrapper classes used.

Whereas [mysql.net connector](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-introduction.html):

> Connector/Net is a fully managed ADO.NET driver written in 100% pure C#. It does not use the MySQL C client library.